# Setting up of Selenium Web driver for SpecBind

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, app-config

I have been asked to create a remote selenium web driver using `browserstack` to test the functionality across all browsers. I have checked the repository to which I have received some of the felds needed:

```
RemoteUrl: http://hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub/
browserstack.user = username 
browserstack.key = password
browserstack.debug = true/false
browserstack.tunnel = true/false
os
OS_version
Version = the browser version
```

I have got the code to create the driver below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "username");
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "password");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
new Uri("http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), capability
);
```

this creates the remote webdriver. However as i am using this with `specbind` I need to create this driver within the `app.config`. which will be stored under a `<browserfactory>` however I am unsure on how to do this, please help!

Answer (score 1):

I have now resolved this issue. From the start URL you need to then put in this browser factory setting:

```
    <browserFactory 
    provider="SpecBind.Selenium.SeleniumBrowserFactory, SpecBind.Selenium">

  <settings>
    <add name="RemoteUrl" value="http://hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub/"/>
    <add name="browser" value="IE" />
    <add name="browser_version" value="8.0"/>
    <add name="os" value ="Windows"/>
    <add name="os_version" value="7" />
    <add name="browserstack.user" value="username" />
    <add name="browserstack.key" value="key" />
  </settings>
```

The various settings configure this to Windows 7 and IE 8. This can be changed accordingly and the Username and Key is given to you by browser stack.